# AEM touch ui dialog 6.3 - Validation Error Icon is overlapping Description icon

Tags: dialog, touch, aem

I have a title component(touch-ui) in my project and made the title field mandatory by setting required(boolean) – true at the title property level. Now, when we save the dialog with an empty title field, validation fires up, but the triangular icon overlaps the description icon in the component. See the screenshot attached. Is there any way to resolve this?

Seeing the same behavior in We.retail title component.

[image]
[image]

Comment: This is by design and works like this OOTB. There might be a way to change that by overriding the validation JS but I’d advise against that since Adobe changes their JS code very often.

Answer (score 1):

It's the same in AEM 6.4. I've kind of assumed this was by design, so that more attention is drawn to the error.

If you look at the JavaScript behind the validation logic, you'll notice that the description icon receives the `u-coral-screenReaderOnly` CSS class as soon as a validation error appears, which results in its disappearance. It's not that the error icon overlaps the info one. The latter is explicitly hidden from sight.

This appears to be part of the Coral UI 2 client library. This isn't something you could fix on your own (an attempt to do that would be tricky and not maintainable). If you need this behaviour changed, you could try your luck contacting Day Care. It does look like a deliberate feature though.